# problem in importing RPI.GPIO as GPIO

Tags: rpi.gpio, apt

Hi guys i suriously tired to solve this problem i have a raspberry pi 3 model B i'm running the raspberry using putty and raspbian using vnc viewr i open the terminal window to creat a simple project "blink LED" using python when i put ***

> $import RPI.GPIO as GPIO

*** the terminal show me this error
[image]

so i try to import the GPIO package in **putty** by putting this code

---

> $ sudo apt-get install python python-dev python-pip

---

so he working but finally he show me this error 
[image]

i think this problem because there is no network in raspberry pi, i have a network in my pc but i can't access with this network to my raspberry pi if there is a way to import those file offline and thaks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here - especially how questions, answers, comments are supposed to be used. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Capitalization matters. Try this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

Note: the lowercase i in RP**i**

You also don't need to run Python with sudo as in your first screenshot. just `python` will work.

As for using apt, you will definitely need a network connection to install or update packages.